# Loop dates in PHP with different steps

Tags: date, loops

i have function, which loop between two different dates, with steps.
In the case, when step is 1 week, it doesn't work good. For example if $first = 2013-09-01 and $last = 2013-11-18 then the last showed week is 2013-11-11 - 2013-11-17

```
function dateRange($first, $last, $step, $format = 'Y-m-d' ) {
    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);

    while( $current <= $last ) 
    {   
        $dates[] = date($format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }

    return $dates;
}

foreach(dateRange('2013-09-01', '2013-11-18', '+1 week') as $day)
{
     echo $day.'<br />';
}
```

Can somebody help me how to edit my function?

Comment: I don't see the problem. It print these for me: 2013-09-01
2013-09-08
2013-09-15
2013-09-22
2013-09-29
2013-10-06
2013-10-13
2013-10-20
2013-10-27
2013-11-03
2013-11-10
2013-11-17

Comment: Yes but $last is '2013-11-18' so it should also print week 2013-11-18 - 2013-11-24